# Sort subdocument using mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to do something very simple but an new to MongoDB! I have a document called Device and a sub-document called Movement. I want to get the last two movement sub-documents out of Device ordered by `last_seen` (a date). Here is what I have along with the error I am getting:

```
Device.findOne({device_id: "1234"}, {movements: { $sort: {last_seen: -1}, $slice: 2 }}, function(err, device){
     ...
});
```

The Error:

`MongoError: >1 field in obj: { $sort: { last_seen: -1 }, $slice: 2 }`

Comment: Please post valid sample documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/):

```
Device.aggregate(
    { $match: { device_id: "1234"}}, // query documents (can return more than one element)
    { $unwind: '$movements'}, //deconstruct the documents
    { $sort: { '$movements.last_seen': -1}},
    { $limit: 2 },
    { $group: { _id: '$device_id', movements: { $push: '$movements }}} //reconstruct the documents
function(err, devices){ 
    //returns an array, probably with one elements depending on `$match` query
});
```

Comment: Here is what I am getting from that: MongoError: the $sort key specification must be an object

Comment: Also I noticed that in the reconstruction that just the ID and the movements are going in. I would like to show all the device data, Do i have to specify each thing I want to show or is there an 'all' selection.

Comment: @gregwinn Fixed the $sort. About the reconstruction you have to specify each field you want. In your case that all fields are the same except the `movements` because of the unwind, you can include them in the `_id` like `{ _id: { device_id: '$device_id', field1: '$field1', ... }, movements: ...}`. After that you can use a projection to remove the _id nesting if you want.